# Asynchronous input notification from Windows console

Tags: python, windows, console

I need to get user input from console asynchronously, i.e. without blocking. I could use the following Python code to check if there is an input available, but it gives 100% CPU load.

```
import msvcrt
while not msvcrt.kbhit():
    pass
```

Is there any other way to do this? Is it possible to register a callback function for keyboard events in console, for example?

UPDATE: I've created a working solution in Python / ctypes. See example at http://techtonik.rainforce.org/2011/03/asynchronous-input-from-windows-console.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the Win32 API, you would normally call `WaitForMultipleObjects` along with your other events to find out which occurred first, the standard input handle itself will be considered triggered whenever any input is available.

> [A process can specify a console input buffer handle in one of the wait functions to determine when there is unread console input. When the input buffer is not empty, the state of a console input buffer handle is signaled.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684961.aspx)

So I would suggest that you look and see whether python has some wrapper for this ability.

Comment: Seems helpful. I can try it with `ctypes`, but does `WaitForMultipleObjects` work with ordinary console? It will help a lot to have working example in a different language before trying to do the same with `ctypes`.

Comment: @techtonik: [This example](http://lxengine.blogspot.com/2010/03/non-blocking-win32-console-input.html) looks like it might help.  And [here's one from Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363677.aspx).

Comment: Thanks. Even though there are problems with clearing the buffer, at least `WaitForMultipleObjects` seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to asynchronously get console input/output.

You could try your code with a sleep to prevent the CPU usage spike.

Comment: That's the most obvious suggestion, but I don't want to miss CPU cycles if a need in heavy background processing arises.

Answer (score 0):

[msvcrt](http://docs.python.org/library/msvcrt.html).getch()

Comment: That's still a blocking function.

Comment: well yeah.  You either use a blocking function, or you poll using up CPU.

Comment: Plenty of other options in native Win32, it just remains to be seen whether python lets you get there from here.  Yes, to some degree all event-driven programming requires some blocking function, the trick is to use a blocking function that processes all types of events, not dedicated to a single one.